# how to display menu items dynamically in react js

Tags: reactjs, api, dynamic, material-ui, menu

[Here is the menu UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcTkB.png)

Trying to load menu and menu item dynamically from backend through redux state.not able render menu items for specific menu.

json Data structre:

```
 menuContext:{
  Define:[{id:1,label:"user"},{id:2,label:"test"}]
  Manage:[{id:1,label:"test2"},{id:2,label:"test3"}]
 }
```

```
function MenuContext() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget)
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
  const { viewService, isError, message } = useSelector(state => state.auth)
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState([])
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("cleaned up");
      dispatch(resetMenuContext())
      setMenu([])
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewService !== undefined) {
      if (viewService?.menuContext !== undefined) {
        const { menuContext } = viewService && viewService
        setMenu(menuContext)
     
      }
    }

  }, [viewService])

  return (
    <>
      {
 Object.entries(menu).map(([key, value]) => (
        <>

          <Button
            id={`button-${key}`}
            aria-controls={open ? `menu-${key}` : undefined}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
            variant="contained"
            disableElevation
            onClick={handleClick}
            endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
            disableRipple
            style={{ textTransform: 'none' }}
          >
            {i18next.t(`label.${key}`)}
          </Button>

          <StyledMenu
            id={`menu-${key}`}
            MenuListProps={{
              'aria-labelledby': `button-${key}`,
            }}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            key={key}
          >

            {
              Object.entries(value).map(({ id }) => (

                <MenuItem>
                  {id}
                </MenuItem>
              ))

            }

          </StyledMenu>

        </>

      ))

      }

    </>

  )
}
```

what changes i need to make, to display menu i items for each menu.

Comment: It would be polite to reduce your problem to a minimum example, to save responders the trouble of going through unnecessary coude such as themeProviders or UI state for the dropdown. Furthermore you call some functions which you wrote yourself? Include the source of those in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Value seems to be an array

```
      {
          value?.map({ id, label }) => (
            <MenuItem key={id}>
              {label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))
      }
```

Comment: its fixed able render value in menu item but when  I click menu button it shows all menu items.

Comment: Can you please explan a bit more, by showing the images of what is rendering and what was expected

Comment: i have multiple menus with menu item. like MANGE, TOOOLS, DEFINE, if i click on any menu button it shows menu items of all menus. for example if i click on MANAGE it shows menu items of all 3 menu. I want to show each menu when i click on it , it must show menu items of that particular menu